# How to prevent Magento to generate urls for disabled categories?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

Using Magento 1.9.x

I have a lot of disabled categories that I'm utilizing in my store to view specific products on Magento frontend.

Magento creates Urls for those disabled categories with and products are assigned to them.

I have this setting **"Use Categories Path for Product URLs"** as **No**

Any suggestion on how to prevent Magento stop generating URL for disabled categories would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this patch does it

https://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/

Test on a dev store first

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I already have this extension installed. Its only working with invisible and disabled products.